# Custom Services and NATS Connection Issues

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am creating a custom service in on a single node instance of CloudFoundry which I build from vcap_dev_setup. I have followed [these instructions](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-collaboration/vcap-services/wiki/How-to-add-a-system-service-to-Cloud-Foundry---step-by-step-guide) to get an idea of what todo when creating new services.

When I try to start the new service gateway by running 'vcap_dev start service_gaeway' I get the following error:

```
Exiting due to NATS error: Could not connect to server on nats://nats:nats@172.16.4.146:4222/
```

The configuration for the :mbus property on the service_gateway is fine and is identical to that of all of the other services which start without issue.

Does anyone know of any reason why a single service could not connect to nats correctly assuming the configuration is correct?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this would be the case, assuming other services are able to connect to NATS

If you are willing to share your changes to VCAP as a patch I will happily take a look, what service are your looking to integrate?

I would also advise posting your query to the VCAP dev google group at https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have NATS running on the IP address: 172.16.4.146 Port: 4222

The IP Address should most likely be your localhost. DHCP most likely has assigned another IP addresst other than 172.16.4.146. Make sure your computer has 172.16.4.146 as IP address. You can check that by doing ifconfig.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky problem may be caused by a version conflict with misleading exception, you could have a try with the latest code;